# Non static members inside a static method

Tags: java

In java my proffesor told us that you cannot use a non static class members inside a static method. He also said that you cannot use the "this" keyword in a static method. Why is that?

Comment: You need to learn what static methods are.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html   http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-static class members and `this` are associated with an instance of the class, while static method is not associated with any instance but the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use non static variables in a static method because a static method can be executed without instancing(creating an object based on..) the class. Since non static variables can change by using the object's methods, the non-static variables are specific to the object. Because you can instance a class multiple times to create multiple objects with which you can use methods to change the non-static variables that belong to the objects, there would be multiple values for this non-static variable. If the static method was able to access the non-static variable, it would not know which value to use. Hence why it isn't able to use it.

As for the `this`, the `this` refers to a non-static variable that belongs to the object. Since you cannot access non-static variables from static methods, you shouldn't call `this` in a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes an example helps. Consider this class:

```
class Foo {
  int bar; // non-static member

  Foo(int bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  static int getBar() {
    return bar; // invalid - what if we have many Foos with different bars?
  }
}
```

Now imagine attemping to use this class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Foo foo1 = new Foo(1); // bar is 1 in this instance
  Foo foo2 = new Foo(2); // bar is 2 in this instance
  int bar = Foo.getBar(); // which instance of Foo would we get bar from?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because both non-static members and the `this` keyword refer to an *instance* of an object. A static method belongs *to the class*, not to the instance so those two things don't mean anything in said context.

Answer (score 0):

Non static class members and `this` keyword are related with class objects and static method related to class.
The thing is `objects` know everything about class so object can access all the static methods  class.
And `class` have `no` information about its `objects` that's why static method can't access objects members.